# Author with Arabic Name

Tags: bibtex, bibliographies, arabic

I am writing an paper (in English) and one of the authors of a paper I'm citing name is in Arabic. The article is written in English.

The BibTex entry:

```
@article{kotini,
     jstor_articletype = {research-article},
     title = {Aristophanes's Response to the Peloponnesian War and the Defeat of the Comic Hero / استجابة أريستوفانيس للحرب الپلوپونيسية واندحار البطل الكوميدي},
     author = {Kotini, Vassiliki and كوتيني, ڨاسيليكي},
     journal = {Alif: Journal of Comparative Poetics},
     number = {30},
     pages = {pp. 134-149},
     url = {http://www.jstor.org/stable/27929850},
     year = {2010},
     publisher = {Department of English and Comparative Literature, American University in Cairo and American University in Cairo Press},
    }
```

What is the way to get this to display properly with the least amount of friction? Currently in the outputted PDF the arabic name and title just don't show up.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! I assume your input encoding is "UTF8" and that you're using either Xe(La)TeX or Lua(La)TeX. You'll need to use the `biblatex` package and the program `biber` to typeset your bibliography; as you've discovered, BibTeX has no idea what to do with Arabic input...

Comment: Not relevant to the TeX problem (which Mico correctly says can only be solved with `biblatex` and `biber`) but the authorship of this paper is quite odd. The actual paper lists only one author (Kotini) in the title, and the entire paper is written in the first person singular, which is very odd for a jointly authored paper. There definitely is an Arabic name in the citation but are you sure it's not just the Arabic version of the actual author (which would match with the fact that there is an Arabic version ofa the title too)?

Comment: @AlanMunn: the Arabic name is just a transliteration of “Kotini, Vassiliki”.

Comment: @KhaledHosny Thanks Khaled. That's what I thought but I don't know Arabic. It seemed very odd to have an Arabic script name for one author of an English article. What's misleading is that they put 'and' between the English name and the transliterated Arabic name.

Answer (score 4):

I'm turning the comment thread into an answer so that we can take this question off of the "unanswered" list.

It is highly unlikely that the situation you are describing (namely one author with an English name and one author with an Arabic name) would ever arise in the real academic world.  Articles in journals are always published in a single language (perhaps with a second language abstract), and therefore the author names will also be in a single language.

In your specific case, the Arabic "author" in your `.bib` file is *not* in fact a second author: the paper only has one author,  "Vassiliki Kotini" and the Arabic part in your `.bib` entry should simply be deleted, since it is in fact the Arabic transliteration of "Vassiliki Kotini".  The journal the article is published in publishes papers in English with Arabic abstracts and bibliography information. Misleadingly, however, it puts the word "and" between the English version of the name and the Arabic version, which probably led to the confusion.